Is this malus baccata?
Sunday 22 September 2024
Location: Vienna 1190, Austria
This tree (which my app can’t identify) reminds me of an apple tree (I am terrible at tree identification). Its fruit are the size of cherries, but taste like apples with a bitter aftertaste. Seeds and fruit stalks are also reminiscent of apples.
I am now thinking it might be malus baccata.









This is a very well put together question! Showing images of all parts of the plant and giving a location makes this a fun question to answer.
You are really close in thinking that this is Malus baccata. However this tree is actually more correctly identified as Malus prunifolia or the Pear Leaf Crabapple.
Let me explain why. Starting with the family, and working down to the species.
Family
We know that this is in the Family Rosaceae or the Rose family. Due to its fruiting nature and alternating leaf pattern. (Yes, apples are in the Rose family, as well as pears, plums, cherries, and most other exported edible fruits)
Genus
Let's keep narrowing down our possibilities.  This tree is in the Malus Genus which is better known as the Apples and Crabapples Genus. There are a two main reasons:

The leaves have a serrated margin as well as being alternate and simple.
The fruit pictured is a globose pome. Bearing distinctive Malus traits. (In more simple words: the fruit resembles an apple or crab-apple)

Apples versus Crab-apples
In order to correctly identify this tree the difference between a crab-apple tree and a regular apple tree must be understood. Britannica sums it up fairly well: 

Crabapple trees are stiffer in form and spinier than the common apple. The plants are deciduous and often have attractive fall foliage. The simple ovate leaves are serrated along the margins and are borne alternately along the twigs. The fragrant white, pink, carmine, or purplish flowers appear early in showy masses—in some species and cultivars as five-petaled blossoms, in others as semidouble (having 6–10 petals) or double (having more than 10 petals) blossoms. The pome fruits often persist through the winter and are generally less than 5 cm (2 inches) in diameter. Source: https://www.britannica.com/plant/crabapple

For the purpose of identification, it only needs to be understood that the tree pictured is a crab-apple tree due to the smaller size of the fruit. For more information on why crab-apple trees are in the same genus as apple trees or what their differences are. Visit the following links:

The most helpful: https://arboretum.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/2009-67-2-Arnoldia.pdf
An interesting forum: https://forum.inaturalist.org/t/apples-vs-crabapples/34888
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40502-023-00712-0
https://www.actahort.org/books/696/696_4.htm
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10722-020-01026-y


Species
One helpful process of getting from genus to species is using the location where the model was found. In this case: Vienna Austria. Using the geographic model of the genus malus on inaturalist.org and the list of all the species in the malus genus. (List Here). We can determine that there are four possible trees in the genus Malus that inhabit that region in Austria.  (with the help of this map). These possible species are:

The Domestic Apple Malus domestica
The European Wild Apple Malus sylvestris
The Pear-Leaf Crabapple Malus prunifolia
The Siberian Crabapple Malus baccata

We can knock out M. domestica and M. sylvestris because we already determined that this tree is a crab-apple tree.
That leaves us with M. baccata and M. prunifolia. From here, these two trees are remarkably similar. The genetic variations of the two trees make it even trickier to differentiate the two trees. This is illustrated here.
There are two primary ways to tell between the two trees. The blossom shape and color, and the fruit size and weight. Since we don't have a sample of the blossom, the best way is to look at the fruit size. M. baccata has a smaller, lighter fruit averaging at about 1-5 grams. While M. prunifolia has a larger, heavier fruit averaging anywhere from 10-25 grams. This confirms this species as Malus prunifolia or the Pear Leaf Crabapple:

Malus prunifolia is a species of crabapple tree known by the common names plumleaf crab apple, plum-leaved apple, pear-leaf crabapple, Chinese apple and Chinese crabapple. It is native to China, and is grown elsewhere for use as an ornamental tree or as rootstock. It reaches from between 3 and 8 meters tall and bears white flowers and yellow or red fruit.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malus_prunifolia

A diagram showing the differences in fruit between M. baccata and M. prunifolia

Journal of the American Society for Horticultural Science J. Amer. Soc. Hort. Sci. 142, 2; 10.21273/JASHS03968-16, https://journals.ashs.org/jashs/view/journals/jashs/142/2/article-p126.xml
A picture of M. baccata. Note the smaller fruit and cleaner leaves

Photo 30691961, (c) Александр Скачко, some rights reserved (CC BY-NC), uploaded by Александр Скачко, https://www.inaturalist.org/photos/30691961
A picture of M. prunifolia, note the alternate leaf placement

Photo 148881668, (c) Magazova Lubov, some rights reserved (CC BY-NC), uploaded by Magazova Lubov
